# Python, I need the following code to finish quicker

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, benchmarking

I need the following code to finish quicker without threads or multiprocessing. If anyone knows of any tricks that would be greatly appreciated. maybe `for i in enumerate()` or changing the list to a string before calculating, I'm not sure.
For the example below, I have attempted to recreate the variables using a random sequence, however this has rendered some of the conditions inside the loop useless ... which is ok for this example, it just means the 'true' application for the code will take slightly longer.
Currently on my i7, the example below (which will mostly bypass some of its conditions) completes in 1 second, I would like to get this down as much as possible.

```
import random
import time
import collections
import cProfile


def random_string(length=7):
    """Return a random string of given length"""
    return "".join([chr(random.randint(65, 90)) for i in range(length)])

LIST_LEN = 18400
original = [[random_string() for i in range(LIST_LEN)] for j in range(6)]
LIST_LEN = 5
SufxList = [random_string() for i in range(LIST_LEN)]
LIST_LEN = 28
TerminateHook = [random_string() for i in range(LIST_LEN)]
#^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Exclude above from benchmark


ListVar = original[:]
for b in range(len(ListVar)):
   for c in range(len(ListVar[b])):

       #If its an int ... remove
       try:
           int(ListVar[b][c].replace(' ', ''))
           ListVar[b][c] = ''
       except: pass

       #if any second sufxList delete
       for d in range(len(SufxList)):
           if ListVar[b][c].find(SufxList[d]) != -1: ListVar[b][c] = ''

       for d in range(len(TerminateHook)):
           if ListVar[b][c].find(TerminateHook[d]) != -1: ListVar[b][c] = ''
   #remove all '' from list
   while '' in ListVar[b]: ListVar[b].remove('')

print(ListVar[b])
```

Comment: You can try to rewrite some parts of your code in C (i.e. finding mstrings in a list). I use `swig` for that. Also, maybe hashes instead of lists would be faster

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve? It's easier for us to answer the question "What is an efficient way to do X", rather than understanding your code and coming up with a better way to do it.

Comment: I want to run a list though a filtration process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListVar = original[:]
```

That makes a shallow copy of ListVar, so your changes to the second level lists are going to affect the original also. Are you sure that is what you want? Much better would be to build the new modified list from scratch.

```
for b in range(len(ListVar)):
   for c in range(len(ListVar[b])):
```

Yuck: whenever possible iterate directly over lists.

```
       #If its an int ... remove
       try:
           int(ListVar[b][c].replace(' ', ''))
           ListVar[b][c] = ''
       except: pass
```

You want to ignore spaces in the middle of numbers? That doesn't sound right. If the numbers can be negative you may want to use the `try..except` but if they are only positive just use `.isdigit()`.

```
       #if any second sufxList delete
       for d in range(len(SufxList)):
           if ListVar[b][c].find(SufxList[d]) != -1: ListVar[b][c] = ''
```

Is that just bad naming? SufxList implies you are looking for suffixes, if so just use `.endswith()` (and note that you can pass a tuple in to avoid the loop). If you really do want to find the the suffix is anywhere in the string use the `in` operator.

```
       for d in range(len(TerminateHook)):
           if ListVar[b][c].find(TerminateHook[d]) != -1: ListVar[b][c] = ''
```

Again use the `in` operator. Also `any()` is useful here.

```
   #remove all '' from list
   while '' in ListVar[b]: ListVar[b].remove('')
```

and that `while` is O(n^2) i.e. it will be slow. You could use a list comprehension instead to strip out the blanks, but better just to build clean lists to begin with.

```
print(ListVar[b])
```

I think maybe your indentation was wrong on that print.

Putting these suggestions together gives something like:

```
suffixes = tuple(SufxList)
newListVar = []
for row in original:
   newRow = []
   newListVar.append(newRow)
   for value in row:
       if (not value.isdigit() and 
           not value.endswith(suffixes) and
           not any(th in value for th in TerminateHook)):
           newRow.append(value)

    print(newRow)
```